# Application Layer Testing

Tags: .net, unit-testing, tdd, domain-driven-design, nsubstitute

I want to test class of Application Layer and not sure about what is better. I have class of Domain Model is Task, e.g.

```
class Task {
   private Clock clock;

   public Guid Id {get; private set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public DateTime StartedDate {get; private set;}

   public Task(Guid id, string name, Clock pClock) {
       Id = id;
       Name = name;
       clock = pClock;
       StartedDate = clock.Now();
   }

}

interface Clock
{
    DateTime Now {get;}
}
```

So I want to test CreateTask method of WorkManagementService class. I can not understand what I should test. Suppose, I write test

```
TestCreateTaskShouldReturnTaskIdWasCreated() 
{
    Guid taskId = Guid.Empty;
    TaskRepository repository = Substitute.For<TaskRepository>();
    repsitory.Add(Arg.Do<Task>(taskArgument => taskId = taskArgument.Id));
    var service = new WorkManagementService(repository);

    var createdTaskId = service.CreateTask("task name");

    Assert.AreNotEqual(Guid.Empty, createdTaskId);
    Assert.AreEqual(taskId, createdTaskId);
}
```

So, I'm not sure if it's good practice. CreateTask method uses Task constructor to create Task and some implementation of Clock interface, so WorkManagementService class depends on them. Is a good way?

I'm sorry if this is confusing.

**UPDATE**
I'm thinking that the first implementation of CreateTask method may be following.

```
 class WorkManegementService
{
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    public WorkManegementService(TaskRepository pTaskRepository)
    {
        taskRepository = pTaskRepository;
    }

    Guid CreateTask(string name)
    {
        var taskId = Guid.NewGuid();
        var task = new Task(taskId, name, new SystemClock());
        try 
        {
            taskRepository.Save(task);

            return taskId;
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            // some handling
        }
    }
}
```

In during further implementation, I'm going to add Task Owner or something similar.

Comment: Please show the `CreateTask` method and the class that it is in. It is not clear from your question how specifically this method is related to your test.

Comment: @NightOwl888, I've updated the question.

Comment: Your test uses the `Create` method, not the `CreateTask` method. If that is not a typo, please post the `Create` method as well.

Comment: @NightOwl888, it's my mistake, sorry. It uses `CreateTask` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could test the creation and the correct initialization of your object but here there is no real logic to test. 
It will be better if you have an intention to test in which context this task is used, what behavior.

Honestly it's unnecessary to unit-test your simple accessors and mutators. It's a waste of time and it doesn't help anyone. The only reason to test the creation it's because there is a specific state you want your object to be in... (like map of a game or a bank account).

**maybe if you show Create method code it will give a better overview of what your method is supposed to do

[Edit]

Your test could verify that your save method have been called...

```
repository.Received().Save(Arg.Any<Task>()); // Arg.Is if you prefer
```

More [here](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/received-calls/)

[Edit2]

For the dependencies you could totally delegate the initialization of the task to another method/class, this way your test could be totally predictable and isolated from other dependencies.
From a purist point of view, a unit-test should test one thing at the time and have limited reason to fail. If you are learning I would advise that you apply strictly this rule.

```
Guid CreateTask(string name)
    {
        var task = this.InitTask(name); // or factory.CreateTask(name) or you can have public function prop that you inject if you like functional way...
        try 
        {
            taskRepository.Save(task);

            return taskId;
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            // some handling
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've updated the question with the implementation of the `CreateTask` method.

Comment: Ok, Thank you. What about dependencies on Task and SystemClock class in the CreateTask method. As I understand if Task or SystemClock constructors throw an exception then the test is failed. I'm not sure if it's correct. Is it clear?

Answer (score 2):

The main purpose of unit testing is to ensure the *business logic* of your application works as expected. The only business logic you have to test in your example is:

1. Ensure the method calls `repository.Save` and the contents of `task` are correct
2. Ensure the taskId is correct
3. Ensure the error handling is working

As for the `Task` object, you might consider testing to ensure the constructor works properly, but it is much more important to unit test your `Clock` class to ensure it is working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tests for `Clock` and `Task` constructor, but it seems that correct execution of `CreateTask` test depends on `Task` and `Clock` classes. So the test implicitly covers 3 classes. Or do I misunderstand that?

Comment: If you have more than one class under test, that is no longer a unit test, that is instead an *integration test*. Integration tests are for testing a larger chunk of the application to ensure the pieces work together. But unit tests should fake all but the one class under test and test each important piece of business logic within that class.

Comment: In fact, a unit test should *always mock* the time so the test gets consistent output that can be asserted. Time is another dependency of the business logic.

Comment: So how can I write a unit test for the CreateTask method which uses `Task` and `SystemClock` inside? I can not mock them. I'm not sure if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here you ask:

> I have tests for Clock and Task constructor, but it seems that correct
>   execution of CreateTask test depends on Task and Clock classes. So the
>   test implicitly covers 3 classes. Or do I misunderstand that?

The `Clock` and `Task` constructor tests are appropriate, and do not require repetition in `CreateTask()` tests.

To aggregate the appropriate guidance above, the correct tests for `WorkManagementService` are as follows:

- **Given** a `CreateTask()` invocation with a null parameter, **then** ensure the error is reported as expected (e.g., throwing an `ArgumentNullException`)
- **Given** a `CreateTask()` invocation with a good parameter, **then** ensure `repository.Save()` is invoked with the proper parameter (by using a mocked constructor-injected repository)
- **Given** a `CreateTask()` invocation with a good parameter **and** a failed `repository.Save()` invocation (thrown exception), **then** ensure `CreateTask()` fails as expected (e.g., rethrowing the exception, throwing a new outer exception, or some other expected error handling)
- **Given** a successful `repository.Save()` invocation, **then** ensure `CreateTask()` returns the expected `Guid`